# Spark is inconsistent with unusually encoded CSV file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

Context:

- As part of data pipeline, I am working on some flat CSV files
- Those files have unusual encoding and escaping rules
- My intention is too preprocess those and convert to parquets for subsequent pipeline steps

MCVE:

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("...").getOrCreate()

min_schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("dummy_col", StringType(), True),
        StructField("record_id", IntegerType(), nullable=False),
        StructField("dummy_after", StringType(), nullable=False),
    ]
)


df = (
    spark.read.option("mode", "FAILFAST")
    .option("quote", '"')
    .option("escape", '"')
    .option("inferSchema", "false")
    .option("multiline", "true")
    .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "true")
    .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", "true")
    .schema(min_schema)
    .csv(f'min_repro.csv', header=True)
)
```

```
dummy_col,record_id,dummy_after
"",1,", Unusual value with comma included"
B,2,"Unusual value with escaped quote and comma ""like, this"
```

CSV parses fine:

```py
df.collect()

[Row(dummy_col=None, record_id=1, dummy_after=', Unusual value with comma included'),
Row(dummy_col='B', record_id=2, dummy_after='Unusual value with escaped quote and comma "like, this')]
```

Yet trivial Spark code on same DF fails with obscure error:

```py
if df.count() != df.select('record_id').distinct().count():
    pass
```

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o357.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 17.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 17.0 (TID 13, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Malformed records are detected in record parsing. Parse Mode: FAILFAST.
...
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Unusual value with comma included""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
```

I don't understand how `.collect()` on same DF can provide correct rows, yet any queries on same DF are failing.

Upstream bug was created: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-39842

Comment: Why `collect` works and `select('record_id')` doesn't work? => maybe  https://medium.com/@smdbilal.vt5815/csv-bad-record-handling-and-its-complications-pyspark-f3b871d652ba

And your malformed record is `""` in `dummy_col`, if you make the emptyValue ("") to `(blank),`, this data doesn't have any issues.  My guess is the this 2 double quotes is considered as escape char + `"`.  That's why the data is shifted left. When you are selecting `record_id`, the error shows it is accessing "Unusual...." data which supposed to be the data for `dummy_after`.

Comment: @Emma yes, this sounds very likely, but still do not explain why shift occurs only in querying, not in simple ".collect()"

Answer (score 0):

Correct way of ignoring , within Data is

1. enclose data within Double quotes.
2. Use option "escapeQuotes", "true"

```
df = ( spark.read.option("mode", "FAILFAST") .option("escapeQuotes", "true") .option("inferSchema", "false") .option("multiline", "true") .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "true") .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", "true") .schema(min_schema) .csv(f'C:/Users/pc/Desktop/sample2.csv', header=True) )
------------------------------------------------------------------------

    >>> df.select('dummy_after').show(truncate=False)
    +-----------------------------------+
    |dummy_after                        |
    +-----------------------------------+
    |, Unusual value with comma included|
    +-----------------------------------+

    >>> if df.count() != df.select('record_id').distinct().count():
    ...    pass
```

Comment: Please correct the formatting

Comment: I expanded min_repro.csv to another "weird" row I am encountering in my input data.

For new min_repro your patch actually flips the behavior, queries work, but `.collect()` crashes with `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Malformed CSV record` in stack trace.

Comment: can you provide some sample data of min_repo.csv. and why are you using df.collect() ?, its expensive operation as it transfers the data to Driver, instead you should use df.show()

Comment: @SachinTiwari I don't see how "expensiveness" of the operation has to do anything with reported problem. Keep in mind that all of the rows will need to be collected anyway, because they'll end up in S3 for subsequent pipeline steps to consume.